# passing session between two contexts

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere

Is there a acceptable way of passing sessions between two sessions?

We have 2 applications on a Websphere application server 7.0. The need is to pass an session from one application to another.

Scenario:
User in one application chooses to switch to another context (application), we want the new application to receive the session data that the user had in the earlier application.

Please note that the two applications reside on the same app server, same JVM as I understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Websphere supports shared session context between wars in a same ear (see ibm-application-ext.xml) This is against the j2ee specifications and you are exposing yourself to vendor lock in. 
You could use a database as a common store for user based information.

Comment: I believe you are correct on this. Also as this support is new for 7.0 and vendor specific I would not trust it to work 100% similarly in the future versions either.

Comment: Actualy, this setting has been around since 6.0 at least.

Comment: @svachon, while you're correct in stating that this is a bad idea, I wouldn't go as far as saying that this is "against the j2ee specification". It's not against the specification; it extends it (and terribly so).